# Can't understand this statement

Tags: np-complete

I was reading some bachelor thesis and it mentioned reducing the hitting set problem to the set cover problem. However I am unable to understand the last line in the referenced paragraph, I would really appreciate if someone can help clarify it. Here is the paragraph:

> In order to reduce the hitting set problem to the set cover problem.
>   Let us think of a function having an instance S for the hitting set
>   problem which will map it to U and F as instances to the set cover
>   problem as follows.
>
> $$f (S) = (U, F )$$
>
> where $U = S$,
>
> $F = ${$A_i |i \in U_S$}
>
> where $U_S = \cup_{B∈S}B, A_i = ${$B|B \in S \ \& \ i\in B\}$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Terrible... $S$ is a set; consider every element $B \in S$ and "sum" them all, getting $U_S=\bigcup_{B \in S} B$.

Comment: The sum of two set is the re-union of all the respective elements: $C \cup D = \{ x \mid x \in C \text { or } x \in D \}$. the same for "multiple" union.

Comment: $A_i$ is a "family" of elements of $S$, i.e. a *subset* of $S$; not all but only those $B \in S$ such that $i \in B$. Thus, fix $i$ and consider in turn each element $B$ of $S$: if $i \in B$, then "throw it" into $A_i$; otherwise, discard it.

Comment: $S$ is a set whose elements are again sets. Thus e.g. $S= \{ C,D \}$ where $C = \{ a,b,c, \}$ and $D = \{ a,x,z \}$. First, we have that $U_S = \{ a,b,c,x,z \}= \bigcup_{B \in S} B= C \cup D$.

Comment: Consider now $a$ as $i$ : $a \in C$ ? YES and $a \in D$ YES. Thus $A_a= \{ C,D \}$. But $b \in C$ and $b \notin D$; thus $A_b = \{ C \}$. And so on.

Comment: Oh, that was tricky!
Thank you very much! :D

Comment: You are welcome :-)